# What are the accident rates for kit built aircraft vs. normal aircraft of the same model?

Tags: safety, general-aviation, accidents, amateur-built

I know that some manufacturers both sell kit and finished version of their aircraft. For a fair comparison of accident rates, i was wondering:

**What are the accident rates for kit built aircraft vs. normal aircraft of the same model?**

Are the home-builds less safe than the company finished aircraft?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Australian Transport Safety Bureau did a report titled:

[Amateur-built aircraft Part 2: Analysis of accidents involving VH-registered non-factory-built aeroplanes 1988-2010](http://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/2007/ar-2007-043%282%29.aspx)

This report specifically covers this and found that the accident rate was three times higher in kit built -vs- similar factory build aircraft:

> **What did this report do**
>
> The ATSB investigated the safety history of amateur-built aircraft in
> Australia through analysis of accident data held in the ATSB’s
> occurrence database from 1988 to 2010. Comparisons were made between
> accidents involving amateur-built aircraft and those involving similar
> factory-built aircraft to help identify whether the rate and types of
> accidents differed between these two groups of aircraft.
>
> **What the ATSB found**
>
> Amateur-built aircraft had an accident rate three times higher than
> comparable factory-built certified aircraft conducting similar flight
> operations between 1988 and 2010. The fatal and serious injury
> accident rate was over five times higher in amateur-built aircraft, in
> particular due to relatively more serious injury accidents. The pilots
> of amateur-built aircraft involved in accidents were significantly
> more experienced overall than factory-built aircraft accident pilots.
> However, they were significantly less experienced on the aircraft type
> that they were flying at the time of the accident.
>
> Over half of the accidents were precipitated by mechanical events,
> which were mainly complete or partial engine failures. Following the
> amateur-built phase one test period, mechanical failures were still
> significantly more common when compared with factory-built aircraft. A
> quarter of accidents were from loss of aircraft control. Structural
> failures were not common precursors in amateur-built aircraft.
> Collision with terrain and forced landing accidents were more frequent
> in amateur-built aircraft. Collisions with terrain, hard landings, and
> runway excursions were more likely to result in a serious injury from
> an amateur-built aircraft accident than for factory-built accidents.

On the other hand, the Experimental Aircraft Association says that homebuilt aircraft have an accident rate of less than 1% higher than the general aviation fleet in their [FAQ](http://www.eaa.org/homebuilders/faq.asp), but this didn't compare homebuilt to factory built in similar models:

> **How Safe Are Amateur-Built/Homebuilt Aircraft?**
>
> Studies by FAA and the National Transportation Safety Board (NTSB)
> show that Amateur-Built/Homebuilt aircraft have an accident rate less
> than one percentage point higher than the general aviation fleet. In
> fact, the accident rate for Amateur-Built/homebuilt aircraft is
> dropping. The total number of registered homebuilt aircraft is
> increasing by about 1,000 per year, while the total number of
> accidents has stayed virtually the same. Another good barometer of
> safety is insurance rates. Companies that insure both homebuilts and
> production aircraft charge about the same rates for owners of either
> type of airplane. That indicates a similar level of risk.

Comment: Should that be 'FAA' rather than 'EAA?'

Comment: @reirab No, EAA is the Experimental Aircraft Association and the specialize in aircraft like kit built airplanes.

Comment: ah, ok, thanks. I didn't notice the link there when I read it the first time. I guess that would have answered my question. I just noticed the quote immediately after it referring to studies by the FAA.